# Max by Group with Condition for a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have data like this:

```
library(data.table)
group <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
cond <- c("N","Y","N","Y","Y","N")
value <- c(2,1,3,4,2,5)

dt <- data.table(group, cond, value)

group cond value
a     N    2
a     Y    1
a     N    3
b     Y    4
b     Y    2
b     N    5
```

I would like to return max value when the cond is Y for the entire group.  Something like this:

```
group cond value max
a     N    2     1
a     Y    1     1
a     N    3     1
b     Y    4     4
b     Y    2     4
b     N    5     4
```

I've tried adding an ifelse condition to a grouped max, however, I end up just returning the no condition of NA when the row doesn't meet the condition:

```
dt[, max := ifelse(cond=="Y", max(value), NA), by = group]
```

Comment: Try `dt[, max := if(all(cond == "Y")) max(value) else NA, by = group]`

Comment: Returned a max column of NA values.

Comment: It was based on your description `would like to return max value when the cond is Y for the entire group.`, in the example it is not as group, 'a' and 'b' both have 'N'

Comment: I think you need `dt[, max := max(value[cond == 'Y']), group]
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that for each 'group' we need to get the `max` of 'value' where the 'cond' is "Y", after grouping by 'group', subset the 'value' with the logical condition (`cond == 'Y'`) and get the `max` value

```
dt[, max := max(value[cond == 'Y']), by = group]
dt
#   group cond value max
#1:     a    N     2   1
#2:     a    Y     1   1
#3:     a    N     3   1
#4:     b    Y     4   4
#5:     b    Y     2   4
#6:     b    N     5   4
```

Comment: @ericbrownaustin  Probably bcz your actual dataset is not `data.table` Try `setDT(dt)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do...

```
dt[CJ(group = group, cond = "Y", unique=TRUE), on=.(group, cond), 
  .(mv = max(value))
, by=.EACHI]

#    group cond mv
# 1:     a    Y  1
# 2:     b    Y  4
```

Using a join like this [will eventually have](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/971) optimization of the `max` calculation.

---

Another way (originally included in @akrun's answer):

```
dt[cond == "Y", mv := max(value), by=group]
```

From the prior link, we can see that this way is already optimized, except for [the `:=` part](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1414).

Comment: Returned an error:

Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, CJ(group = group, cond = "Y", unique = TRUE),  : 
unused arguments (on = .(group, cond), by = .EACHI)

Comment: @ericbrownaustin It works for the example in the question because `dt` is a data.table there, while you're testing with a data.frame, maybe? You can use `setDT(dt)` to adjust it.